# Does $\sum_{i,j\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(i+j)^2}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Does  $\sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(i+j)^2}$ exist?

I tried with $ \frac{(i+j)}{2}\ge \sqrt{ij} $ but this seem to be of no work as for each fixed $i$, $\sum_{j} \frac{1}{ij}$ does not exist. We need a better estimate. But I can not find one.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In title and first line your question has denominator $(j+j)^2$ but sum is over all $i,j$ --- is that really what you mean?

Comment: This notation is meaningless if you don't say where $i$ and $j$ live.

Comment: Obviously, they are natural numbers.

Comment: In which order are you summing? But I think it cannot converge see it by replacing your sum with integral  $1\leq x,y\leq \infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** As all the terms are positive, we get that the series converges iff any of its reorderings converges. Thus, we can collect all the $(i,j)$ which add up to $p$ and sum over all $p$, i.e.
$$ \sum_{i,j\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}} \frac{1}{(i+j)^2}
= \sum_{p\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}} \frac{\vert \{ (i,j)\in (\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})^2 \ : \ i+j=p\} \vert }{p^2}. $$
Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

By double counting we have that

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+j)^2}= \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k-1}{k^2}$$

[image]